HTTP_GET using QSYS2.HTTP_GET in RPGLE
Here is the curl request that works
curl -X 'GET' \   
'https://myfullurlhere' \   
-H 'accept: text/plain' \   
-H 'X-API-Key: myapikey'  

The code is RPGLE ^^FREE
I am trying to use the SQL functions so here is how i set up my options
exec sql values json_object(                                     
 'basicAuth' value 'X-API-Key: myapikey',
 'header' value 'accept: text/plain'   
 )                                     
into :options;                        

then my call 
exec SQL                                       
     values QSYS2.HTTP_GET(:urlRest, :options) 
     into :response;                           

This causes 38501 SQL error.
Any ideas how to make this work?
Thanks, Kita
I've tried several ways to send the options but to no avail.

Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using
